# INVALID_FLD_VALUE when creating Customer Deposit in SuiteScript

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to create a customer deposit in SuiteScript 2.0. I am having troubles getting the account onto the customer deposit.

```
function createCustomerDeposit(data){
    var record          = data.modules.record;
    var salesorder      = data.salesorder.id;
    var customerid      = data.customerid;
    var transactionid   = data.transactionid;
    var payment_amount  = data.payment_amount;

    var accountREC = record.load({
        type    : record.Type.ACCOUNT,
        id      : 145
    });

    var customerDepositREC = record.create({
        type : record.Type.CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT
    }).setValue({
        fieldId : 'entity',
        value   : customerid
    }).setValue({
        fieldId : 'salesorder',
        value   : salesorder
    }).setValue({
        fieldId : 'payment',
        value   : payment_amount
    }).setValue({
        fieldId : 'undepfunds',
        value   : 'F'
    }).setValue({
        fieldId : 'account',
        value   : accountREC
    }).setValue({
        fieldId : 'memo',
        value   : transactionid
    }).save({
        ignoreMandatoryFields : true
    }); 
}
```

ID 145 is the ID to the account that I want. I can confirm it is loading the correct account for accountREC. But when I try to save this Customer Deposit is doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the initialization of the Customer Deposit. Instead of trying to set the account and salesorder fields, I needed to use the defaultValues param when creating the CD.

```
function createCustomerDeposit(data){
    var record          = data.modules.record;
    var salesorder      = data.salesorder;
    var customerid      = data.customerid;
    var transactionid   = data.transactionid;
    var payment_amount  = data.payment_amount;

    var accountREC = record.load({
        type    : record.Type.ACCOUNT,
        id      : 145
    });

    var customerDepositREC = record.create({
        type : record.Type.CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT,
        defaultValues: {
            entity: customerid,
            salesorder: salesorder.id,
        }
    });
    customerDepositREC.setValue({
        fieldId : 'paymentmethod',
        value : PAYMENT_METHOD_DIRECT_DEPOSIT
    });
    customerDepositREC.setValue({
        fieldId : 'payment',
        value   : payment_amount
    });
    customerDepositREC.setValue({
        fieldId : 'memo',
        value   : transactionid
    });
    customerDepositREC.setValue({
        fieldId : 'undepfunds',
        value   : 'F'
    });
    customerDepositREC.setValue({
        fieldId : 'account',
        value   : accountREC.id
    });
    customerDepositREC.save(); 
}
```